# Would you please give me some easy prove such that I can understand this.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

let $b$ be a prime number, and $a$ be any quadratic non-residue(mob $b$), i.e. $x^2 \equiv a \ (mod \ b)$ has no solutions in integers. Then the algebra $A=( \frac{a,b} { \mathbb{Q}})$ is a division algebra.

I have seen the proof of this in the book Fuchsian Groups, Svetlana Katok, at the page 116-117.But I could not understand it .Would you please give me some easy prove such that I can understand this.

Answer (score 0):

The central simple algebra
$$A=\left(\frac{a,b}{\Bbb Q}\right)$$
is isomorphic to $M_2(\Bbb Q)$ iff the quadratic form $Q(x,y,z)=x^2-ay^2-bz^2$
is isotropic (that is there is a solution $(x,y,z)\ne(0,0,0)$ to $(x,y,z)=0$
to over $\Bbb Q$)
and is a division algebra otherwise. So for $A$ to be a division algebra,
one requires $a$ to be a non-square over $\Bbb Q$, and moreover $b$ not to
be a norm of an element of the quadratic field $\Bbb Q(\sqrt a)$.
(These are the conditions that $Q(x,1,0)=0$ and $Q(x,y,1)$ have no
solutions over $\Bbb Q$.)

If $a=p$ is an odd prime, then $a$ is certainly not a square of a rational.
Moreover if $b$ is a quadratic non-residue of $p$, then there is no
solution to $x^2-py^2=b$ over $\Bbb Q$. If there is a solution
with $p$ dividing the denominator of $x$ or $y$, then $p$ must divide
the denominators of $x^2$ and $py^2$ the same number of times; impossible
on parity grounds. Otherwise $x$ and $y$ are $p$-integers, and then
$x^2-py^2\equiv b\pmod p$ has a solution; impossible as $b$ is
a quadratic non-residue modulo $p$.

But if $a=2$ we can have $A\cong M_2(\Bbb Q)$, say if $b\equiv\pm1\pmod 8$
is a prime.